# Able to get basic Rook/Ceph example to work, but all data apparently sits on a single node

Tags: kubernetes, ceph, kubernetes-rook

Using Rook 0.9.3 I was able to bring up a Ceph-based directory for a MySQL-database on a three-node Kubernetes cluster (1 master, two workers) simply as follows:

```
kubectl create -f cluster/examples/kubernetes/ceph/operator.yaml
kubeclt create -f cluster/examples/kubernetes/ceph/cluster.yaml
vim cluster/examples/kubernetes/ceph/storageclass.yaml # change xfs to ext4
kubectl create -f cluster/examples/kubernetes/ceph/storageclass.yaml
kubectl create -f cluster/examples/kubernetes/mysql.yaml
```

When I now `bash` into the pod `wordpress-mysql-*` I can see that `/var/lib/mysql` is mounted from `/dev/rbd1`. If I create a random file in this directory and then delete the pod, the file has persisted when a new instance of the pod comes up.

My first worker contains these directories in `/var/lib/rook`: `mon-a` `mon-c` `mon-d` `osd0` `rook-ceph`. My second worker contains only one directory in `/var/lib/rook`: `mon-b`. This and other evidence (from `df`) suggest that Rook (and by extension Ceph) stores all of its file data (e.g. all blocks that constitute the mounted `/var/lib/mysql`) in `/var/lib/rook/osd0`, i.e. once on a single node.

I would have expected that blocks are distributed across several nodes so that when one node (the first worker, in my case) fails, data access is still available. Is this a naive expectation? If not, how can I configure Rook accordingly? Also, I have second, unformatted disks on both worker nodes, and I would prefer for Rook/Ceph to use those. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: why rook?I use ceph. it is better than rook. rook have a lot of problem

Comment: @yasinlachini Can you please elaborate?

Comment: you can not resize volume in rook. and if you have problem you can not easily solve it. but in ceph because you are managing osd you have better management.

Comment: @yasinlachini I assume these benefits are to be had if one is a Ceph expert, which I am not (yet).

Answer (score 1):

for using other partition as osd 
you should change cluster.yml and add

```
nodes:
- name: "kube-node1"
  devices:
  - name: "sdb"
- name: "kube-node2"
  devices:
  - name: "sdb"
- name: "kube-node3"
  devices:
  - name: "sdb"
```

Comment: Excellent. Do you also know how this will interact with `dataDirHostPath`?

Comment: No. now i use ceph